# Interface MultiplePermissionsListener does not have constructors

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, libraries

I am trying to use the [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library with Kotlin and I am having the following problem:

In this method i have a error with the MultiplePermissionsListener(), the error says:

> Interface MultiplePermissionsListener does not have constructors

```
fun takeCameraImage() {
         Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg"
                            val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCacheImagePath(fileName!!))
                            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: List<PermissionRequest>,token: PermissionToken) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
     }
```

I have little experience with Kotlin and I don't know what exactly may be happening, I don't know how to fix it, I could use some help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiplePermissionsListener` is an interface and can thus not be instantiated. You need to create an anonymous class that implements the `MultiplePermissionsListener` interface using a so called object expression. It's simple. Replace

```
MultiplePermissionsListener()
```

with

```
object : MultiplePermissionsListener
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions for further details. You also need to replace `@Override` annotations with the Kotlin `override` keyword, i.e. instead of

```
@Override
fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: List<PermissionRequest>,token: PermissionToken) {
    token.continuePermissionRequest();
}
```

you have to write

```
override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: List<PermissionRequest>,token: PermissionToken) {
    token.continuePermissionRequest();
}
```

Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods for more information.